# Spring Security: Cannot convert value of type [ ...] to required type [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutSuccessHandler]

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I couldn't figure out the problem. I have gone through lots of spring-security questions but couldn't understand where I am wrong.

My POM.xml (partial)

```
 <!--depencdency for Spring Security-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

web.xml

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>web</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
    <filter>
     <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
     <filter-class>
     org.sitemesh.config.ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter
     </filter-class>
 </filter>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
   </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint"
               authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">

    <security:intercept-url access="hasRole('0101-01-VIEW')" pattern="/personalInformation.jsp"/>

    <security:custom-filter position="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="concurrentSessionFilter"/>
    <security:custom-filter before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="authFilter"/>

    <security:custom-filter after="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER" ref="ajaxTimeoutRedirectFilter"/>
    <security:form-login always-use-default-target="false" authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
                         default-target-url="/home" login-page="/login"
                         login-processing-url="/auth"
                         authentication-details-source-ref="authenticationDetialsSource"

                         username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"
                         authentication-success-handler-ref="loginSuccessHandler"
                         authentication-failure-handler-ref="loginFailureHandler"/>

    <security:logout logout-url="/logout" success-handler-ref="loginSuccessHandler"
                     invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JESSIONID"/>

    <security:session-management session-authentication-strategy-ref="sas" invalid-session-url="/login"/>
    <security:access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler"/>
    <security:http-basic/>
    <security:csrf/>
</security:http>
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager" erase-credentials="true">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" id="sessionRegistry"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder"/>
<bean class="com.security.WebAuthenticationDetialsSource" id="authenticationDetialsSource"/>
<bean class="com.security.AjaxTimeoutRedirectFilter" id="ajaxTimeoutRedirectFilter"/>

<bean class="com.security.WebAuthenticationProvider" id="authenticationProvider">
    <property name="loginSerivice" ref="loginService"/>
    <property name="authenticationDetialsSource" ref="authenticationDetialsSource"/>
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/>
</bean>

<bean class="com.security.AuthenticationEntryPoint" id="authenticationEntryPoint">
    <constructor-arg name="loginFormUrl" value="/login"/>

</bean>

<bean class="com.security.WebAccessDeniedHandler" id="accessDeniedHandler">
    <property name="accessDeniedUrl" value="403"/>
    <property name="loginSerivice" ref="loginService"/>

</bean>

<bean class="com.security.LoginSuccessHandler" id="loginSuccessHandler">
    <constructor-arg name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/home"/>
    <property name="loginSerivice" ref="loginService"/>
</bean>

<bean class="com.security.LoginFailureHandler" id="loginFailureHandler">
    <constructor-arg name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login?error"/>
    <property name="loginSerivice" ref="loginService"/>
</bean>

<bean class="com.security.LogoutSuccessHandler" id="logoutSuccessHandler">
    <constructor-arg name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/login"/>
</bean>

<bean class="com.security.LogoutFailureHandler" id="logoutFailureHandler">
    <property name="loginSerivice" ref="loginService"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter" id="concurrentSessionFilter">
    <constructor-arg name="sessionRegistry" ref="sessionRegistry"/>
    <constructor-arg name="expiredUrl" value="/login"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter" id="authFilter">
    <property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas"/>
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy"
      id="sas">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy">
                <constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry"/>
                <property name="maximumSessions" value="1"/>
                <property name="exceptionIfMaximumExceeded" value="true"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy">
                <constructor-arg ref="sessionRegistry"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

LoginSuccessHandler Class:

```
public class LoginSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
   private ILoginSerivice loginSerivice;

   public void setLoginSerivice(ILoginSerivice loginSerivice) {
     this.loginSerivice = loginSerivice;
 }

   public LoginSuccessHandler(String defaultTargetUrl) {
     super(defaultTargetUrl);
 }

  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
     super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
     LoginDTO user = (LoginDTO) authentication.getPrincipal();
     HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
     int sessionTimeOut = user.getSessionTimeOut() * 60;
     session.setMaxInactiveInterval(sessionTimeOut);

      if (user.getKeepLoginRecordYN()) {
         String workStationIp = request.getRemoteAddr();
         loginSerivice.keepLoginRecord(user.getUserName(),user.getBranchCode(),workStationIp);

         }
      }
    }
```

Error file:

```
  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating
  bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': 
  Cannot resolve reference to bean org.springframework.security.web
    .DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0'while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is
     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating  bean with name  
     'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': 
    Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#5fa7c2' of type  
  [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter] 
  while setting constructor argument with key [4]; nested exception is 
  org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error
  creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5fa7c2': Unsatisfied dependency 
  expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type
 [java.lang.String]: Could not convert constructor argument value of type 
  [com.security.LoginSuccessHandler] to required type [java.lang.String]:
  Failed to convert value of type 'com.security.LoginSuccessHandler' to 
  required type 'java.lang.String'; nested exception is 
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
  [com.security.LoginSuccessHandler] to required type [java.lang.String]: 
   no matching editors or conversion strategy found
  Related cause:  
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error 
 creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5fa7c2': Unsatisfied dependency 
 expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type  [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutSuccessHandler]
 : Could not convert constructor argument value of type 
 [com.security.LoginSuccessHandler] to required type  [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutSuccessHandler]
  : Failed to convert value of type 'com.security.LoginSuccessHandler'
   to required type'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout. LogoutSuccessHandler';
 nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert 
 value of type [com.security.LoginSuccessHandler] 
 to required type org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutSuccessHandler]
: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Comment: Have you actually READ the error? You are trying to pass a `LoginSuccessHandler` to a field that expects a `LogoutSuccesHandler`.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comment from M. Deinum; the error message states that Spring is expecting a `LogoutSuccessHandler` but you passed a `LoginSuccessHandler` in the following configuration block:

```
<security:logout logout-url="/logout" success-handler-ref="loginSuccessHandler"
                     invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JESSIONID"/>
```

Comment: Thanks M. Deinum and Kylem. I have changed by logoutSuccessHandler. But problem remain same.